# Solving simultaneous equations with imaginary numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

$$ (1+i)z + (1-i)w = 1 $$
$$(1-i)z + 2iw = i $$

What is the answer to the simultaneous equations? I got $ w = \frac 34 + \frac 14 i $

However, the mark scheme of the question says $ w = \frac 35 + \frac 15 i $

Am I wrong or is the mark scheme wrong?

Comment: Plug it in and find out

Comment: You're apparently wrong, checked it on Mathematica.

Comment: actually a 2 by 2 linear system, can be solved, reliably, by inverting the matrix of coefficients

Answer (score 1):

Write in polar form (usually makes algebra easier):
$$\sqrt 2 e^{i\pi/4}z+\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi/4}w=1$$
$$\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi/4}z+2 e^{i\pi/2}w=e^{i\pi/2}$$
Multiply second equation by $e^{i\pi/2}$ and subtract from first equation to get $$(\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi/4}+2)w=2$$ so $$w = \frac{2}{\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi/4}+2}= \frac{2}{3-i} \cdot\frac{3+i}{3+i}=\frac{6+2i}{10}=\frac 35 +\frac15i $$

Answer (score 0):

In order to eliminate $z$, we add the first equation multiplied by $(1-i)$ and the second one multiplied by $-(1+i)$ : 
$$(1-i)((1+i)z + (1-i)w)-(1+i)((1-i)z + 2iw) = (1-i)-(1+i)i,$$
that is
$$((1-i)^2-2i(1+i))w = 2-2i$$
or
$$(-2i+1)w=1-i\implies w=\frac{1-i}{1-2i}=\frac{(1-i)(1+2i)}{1+2^2}=\frac{1-i+2i+2}{5}= \frac 35 + \frac 15 i.$$

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I understand your method, however how do you get to there? (I would never have thought of multiplying by (1-i). Also could you please check [link](https://pasteboard.co/GDLdp98.jpg) my method and which parts are wrong? I've re did it many times and I don't see what I did wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @L.Tommy The denominator of the fraction is $2^2+4^2=20$ and not $16$. Check the multiplication. The numbers that I used are the coefficients of $z$. $(1-i)$ is the coefficient of $z$ in the first one and $(1-i)$ is the coefficient of $z$ in the second one.

Answer (score 0):

from the second equation we get $$w=\frac{i-(1-i)z}{2i}$$b plugging this in the first equation we get
$$(1+i)z+(1-i)\frac{i-(1-i)z}{2i}=1$$
can you solve this?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve it. I did the same thing before, but started with z instead. I must have done something wrong with the substituting.